# Responsive CSS-JS-Slideshow thumbs

Tags: css, css-float, flexbox, multiple-columns

I am working on a slideshow combining css and javascript, but currently I  have no idea how to realize the planed design as it need to be responsive for different screen-sizes.

Following I've added a jpg visualizing the planned Layout:
[Visualization of Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yORh.jpg)

My approaches so far have been flexbox and float, but flexbox doesn't allow a 2 column 1 box : 2 box approach and float doesn't help with the adaption for different screen-sizes (wrap).

Does anyone have an idea for an approach? I realy want to avoid using different css for the 3 szenarios described in the picture above